# Range Background Color Change on Button

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook in which I am trying to use a macro which would run using a button to take colors from a "Key Tab" and change the format to match that of the key. I have a function that I've used to obtain the colorIndex and have placed it in the third column of the Key.

What I would like to format is a range of cells across multiple columns.

Desired Range to change:
"E5:E25,G5:G25,K5:K25,L5:L25,M5:M25,T5:T25,U5:U25,V5:V25,W5:W25"

I've looked and have tried a couple different things but none seem to work. I would to see how someone would code the change of color based on the key. Conditional Formatting isn't an option as the worksheet could change so the conditions would have to be changed each time.

Comment: It's unclear what your "key tab" looks like and hoe that's used to determine colors.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a **good** answer to this question given the information? Please upload relevant photos to support your question and share any code if it is relevant. Right now, it is completely unclear what you are trying to do. It also may help if you take a [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. I placed my color indices in the first column and the colors in the second column, but you can change it to fit your needs exactly. I based my code off of some assumptions as the question needs/needed some extra explanation.  If you need more assistance please let me know.  Below is my attempt:

```
    Option Explicit

    'This is simply an easy call that you could substitute for a button click.
    Sub RunIT()
        CalcColorKeys "ThisSheet", True
    End Sub

    'This can be called on a button press event
    Sub CalcColorKeys(strMainSheetName As String, blnSingleLineColor As Boolean)
        Randomize  'This is required for the Rnd() function

        Dim intI As Integer
        Dim intJ As Integer
        Dim intK As Integer
        Dim rngUnion As Range
        Dim strSht As String
        Dim rngColor As Range
        Dim intR As Integer
        Dim objRefCell As Object

        Dim rngKeys As Range
        Dim vntRanges() As Variant

        strSht = strMainSheetName

        'These are the ranges that you want to change
        vntRanges = Array("E5:E25", "G5:G25", "K5:K25", "L5:L25", "M5:M25", _
                          "T5:T25", "U5:U25", "V5:V25", "W5:W25")

        'This is your reference "keys" range
        Set rngKeys = Worksheets("Keys").Range("A2:B12")

        'This is just a random number between 0 and 10 to get the row that
        '  the color lies on (You can change this to fit your needs).
        intR = Rnd() * 10
        For intI = 1 To rngKeys.Rows.Count
            If intR = CInt(rngKeys(intI, 1).Value) Then
                Set rngColor = rngKeys(intI, 2)

                Exit For
            End If
        Next intI

        'Now, join all of the data
        For intI = 0 To UBound(vntRanges)
            If intI = 0 Then
                Set rngUnion = Worksheets(strSht).Range(vntRanges(intI))
            Else
                Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, Worksheets(strSht).Range(vntRanges(intI)))
            End If
        Next intI

        Set objRefCell = rngColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior
        'I put this in to give you two different options for coloring!
        If blnSingleLineColor Then
            'And finally, go through it all and color it!
            With rngUnion.Interior
                .Pattern = objRefCell.Pattern
                .PatternColorIndex = objRefCell.PatternColorIndex

                'The ThemeColors run from 1 to 12 and therefore cannot be zero!
                '   see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlthemecolor
                If objRefCell.ThemeColor > 0 Then
                    .ThemeColor = CLng(objRefCell.ThemeColor)
                End If
                .TintAndShade = objRefCell.TintAndShade
                .PatternTintAndShade = objRefCell.PatternTintAndShade
            End With
        Else
            'OR, You can go through each cell and colorize them that way.
            For intI = 1 To rngUnion.Areas.Count
                For intJ = 1 To rngUnion.Areas(intI).Rows.Count
                    For intK = 1 To rngUnion.Areas(intI).Columns.Count
                        With rngUnion.Areas(intI).Cells(intJ, intK).Interior
                            .Pattern = objRefCell.Pattern
                            .PatternColorIndex = objRefCell.PatternColorIndex

                            'The ThemeColors run from 1 to 12 and therefore cannot be zero!
                            '   see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlthemecolor
                            If objRefCell.ThemeColor > 0 Then
                                .ThemeColor = CLng(objRefCell.ThemeColor)
                            End If
                            .TintAndShade = objRefCell.TintAndShade
                            .PatternTintAndShade = objRefCell.PatternTintAndShade
                        End With
                    Next intK
                Next intJ
            Next intI
        End If

        Set objRefCell = Nothing
        Set rngUnion = Nothing
        Set rngKeys = Nothing
        Set rngColor = Nothing

    End Sub
```

and Finally, some screen shots:

[image]

[image]